# Can localized fluid perturbations be accelerated by pressure gradients?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, waves, solitons, magnetohydrodynamics

I would like to know if there are any examples in fluid dynamics (or continuum dynamics) of small perturbations (or waves, solitons, or other "localized" solutions of the fluid) being accelerated in the presence of a uniform "background" pressure gradient?

If no, is it known how small amplitude waves behave in the presence of a weak/strong "background" pressure gradient?

Answer (score 1):

I think the [Rayleigh-Taylor instability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh%E2%80%93Taylor_instability) may be considered to be amplified under a pressure gradient.

Due to the difference in densities, there is a pressure gradient across the interface which becomes unstable after a certain time. The instability grows exponentially in time according to an amplitude on the order of:

$$a\propto\exp\left(\sqrt{A}\right)$$

where $A=\frac{\rho_{heavy}-\rho_{light}}{\rho_{heavy}+\rho_{light}}$. Clearly, a larger density difference leads to a faster growing instability.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure that my answer fits with your request of a "uniform" background pressure gradient, but anyway it's a related subject.

Have you considered perturbations of a fluid parcel in a hydrostatically balanced atmosphere? Conservation of momentum here relates the pressure gradient to the gravitational acceleration. It can be shown that perturbed fluid parcels will oscillate about their equilibrium position at the Brunt Visalia frequency.

Comment: Thanks it's the closest answer so far to the kind of thing I'm interested in.